# R Confusion Matrix - the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Tags: r, logistic-regression, forecasting, confusion-matrix

I have a dataframe called `PowderyMildewEpidemic`. I computed a logistic regression forecast and would like to get the model's confusion matrix. I am using the caret package and the `confusionMatrix` function. How do I resolve this issue?

I checked nlevels for each as well, and both return 0.

```
nlevels(ifelse(Mildew.predict2 > 0.5, 1, 0))
nlevels(PowderyMildewEpidemic[11:12, ]$Agree)
```

---

***PowderyMildewEpidemic:*** dput(PowderyMildewEpidemic)

```
structure(list(Year = c(1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 
1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 2000), Outbreak = c("Yes", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), MaxTemp = c(30.14, 
30.66, 26.31, 28.43, 29.57, 31.25, 30.35, 30.71, 30.71, 33.07, 
31.5, 29.5), RelHumidity = c(82.86, 79.57, 89.14, 91, 80.57, 
67.82, 61.76, 81.14, 61.57, 59.76, 68.29, 79.14)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Outbreak = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), MaxTemp = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), RelHumidity = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**My code:**

```
PowderyMildewEpidemic$Agree <- ifelse(PowderyMildewEpidemic$Outbreak == "Yes", 1, 0)

# Forecast for year 1997
# train2: 1987-1996 data used for training
train2 <- PowderyMildewEpidemic[1:10, ]

# Logistic regression model
Mildew.lr2 <- glm(formula = Agree ~ MaxTemp + RelHumidity, data = train2, family = "binomial")
summary(Mildew.lr2)

# Prediction
Mildew.predict2 <- predict(Mildew.lr2, PowderyMildewEpidemic[11:12, ], type = "response")
Mildew.predict2

# Prediction for year 1997
Mildew.predict2[1]

# Logistic regression classification matrix for year 1997
confusionMatrix(as.factor(ifelse(Mildew.predict2 > 0.5, 1, 0)), as.factor(PowderyMildewEpidemic[11:12, ]$Agree))
```

**Error:**

```
Error in confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(ifelse(Mildew.predict2 > 0.5, : 
the data cannot have more levels than the reference
```

---

**Update:**

```
n1 <- factor(ifelse(Mildew.predict2 > 0.5, 1, 0), levels = c(0, 1))
n2 <- factor(PowderyMildewEpidemic[11:12, ]$Agree, levels = c(0, 1))

confusionMatrix(n1, n2)
```

Comment: The last two values of `Outbreak` are both `"No"` and `Agree` became both `0`, the factor will have that one level only. Instead of `as.factor` set the levels explicitly with `factor(., levels = c(0, 1))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Could you please check my update and see if it is correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is correct. Also, `PowderyMildewEpidemic$Agree[11:12]` seems more idiomatic.